# Cannot Resolve Method- Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Trying to figure out why I'm getting a 'setObservationCode is never used' error in the second method. The second snippet shows the unit test where's it being used. With the unit test, it's giving me a 'Cannot resolve method 'setObservationCode' in 'ResourceHandler' error. I seen a few people say they resolve the error by invalidating the caches and restarting but that has been unsuccessful for me.

```
public class ResourceHandlerTest extends TestCase {

    FhirContext ctx = null;
    IParser parser = null;

    // Other methods...

    public String getId(Resource resource) {
        if (resource.getIdElement() != null) {
            // Use IdType to extract the ID without additional details such as base URL or resource type.
            IdType idType = resource.getIdElement();
            return idType.getIdPart();
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the resource does not have an ID.
            return null; // Or throw an exception, depending on your requirements.
        }
    }

    public Observation setObservationCode(Observation observation, Coding coding) {
        if (observation.getCode() == null) {
            observation.setCode(new CodeableConcept().addCoding(coding));
        } else {
            observation.getCode().addCoding(coding);
        }
        return observation;
    }

    
public Observation setObservationCode(Observation observation, Coding coding) {
            if (observation.getCode() == null) {
                observation.setCode(new CodeableConcept().addCoding(coding));
            } else {
                observation.getCode().addCoding(coding);
            }
            return observation;
        }
    
      public Observation setObservationCode(Observation observation, String system, String code, String display) {
            System.out.println("Debug: Observation Before - " + observation);
    
            System.out.println("Debug: System - " + system);
            System.out.println("Debug: Code - " + code);
            System.out.println("Debug: Display - " + display);
    
            Coding coding = new Coding().setSystem(system).setCode(code).setDisplay(display);
    
            return setObservationCode(observation, coding);
        }

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void testSetObservationCode() throws Exception {
            if (ctx == null) ctx = FhirContext.forR4();
            if (parser == null) parser = ctx.newJsonParser();
    
            String observationJsonFile = "src/resources/observation.json";
            String observationJson = "";
            try {
                observationJson = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(observationJsonFile)));
            }
            catch (Exception e) { System.err.println("Failed to read observation.json file."); }
    
            Observation correctObservation = parser.parseResource(Observation.class, observationJson);
    
            ResourceHandler studentResourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
    
            String expectedSystem = "http://example.com/system";
            String expectedCode = "12345";
            String expectedDisplay = "Test Code";
    
            Coding coding = new Coding().setSystem(expectedSystem).setCode(expectedCode).setDisplay(expectedDisplay);
            Observation modifiedObservation = studentResourceHandler.setObservationCode(correctObservation, coding);
    
            assertEquals(expectedSystem, modifiedObservation.getCode().getCodingFirstRep().getSystem());
            assertEquals(expectedCode, modifiedObservation.getCode().getCodingFirstRep().getCode());
            assertEquals(expectedDisplay, modifiedObservation.getCode().getCodingFirstRep().getDisplay());
    
        }
```

Comment: You haven't shown what class `setObervationCode` is in, and you haven't shown what class `new ResourceHandler()` creates, so it's not possible to help. Please edit your question. Include package information.

Comment: So your `setObservationCode` methods are on the `ResourceHandlerTest` class?

Answer (score 0):

You've called the first method in the test but not the second one.

Line 4 from last in the test has 2 args which is the first. So intellij detects no usage of the second one.

```
Observation modifiedObservation = studentResourceHandler.setObservationCode(correctObservation, coding);
```

Looking at the structure of the main code block you should be ideally calling the second definition (which has 4 args) which in turn calls the other one.

Comment: Observation modifiedObservation = studentResourceHandler.setObservationCode(Observation observation, String system, String code, String display); 

When I attempted to call the second definition, I'm getting error "cannot resolve observation",  "cannot resolve system",  "cannot resolve code",  "cannot resolve display",